# GCC Fatal error output: no such file

Tags: 14.04, gcc, programming, c

I been trying to compile a c file with

`gcc filename.c -o outputfilename`

but gcc gives

```
gcc: error: No such  file or directory<br>
gcc: fatal error: no input files<br>
compilation terminated.
```

I changed the file permission to `777`.

I made sure that my current working directory is the same place as the file.
And I also made sure that it is a  C source `code(text/x-csrc)` file type.

Comment: That almost certainly means there isn't a file named *exactly* `filename.c` in the current directory - perhaps it is named `filename.c ` (with a trailing space) or some such - what does `ls -b file*` say? The .c file shouldn't need more than read permissions BTW.

Answer (score 0):

i run this test like you:

```
 $ gcc main.c -o test2
 $ ./test2
this is your number`s = 13 with string = 13
```

what files in my folder:

```
 $ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  401 Окт 15 00:54 main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan  204 Окт 12 00:01 main.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 dan dan 1984 Окт 15 00:54 main.o
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 8720 Ноя  3 00:09 test2
```

gcc look *.c files only in working directory, so to check this:

```
 $ pwd
/home/dan/git/C/test1
```

and lets run compile in wrong directory:

```
 $ cd ..
 $ pwd
/home/dan/git/C
 $ gcc main.c -o test2
gcc: error: main.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

1. so make sure your work dir is correct, use CD command to change you current dir, more in "man cd"
2. start to use MAKE utill
3. you don't need give *.c files exec permission

Comment: You can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. With super-user privileges you need `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt ...` or `gksudo env LC_MESSAGES=POSIX synaptic` (for graphical applications).